# Top-10 mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm in need of a better way of retrieving top 10 distinct UID from some tables I have.

The setup:

- Table user_view_tracker
- Contains pairs of {user id (uid), timestamp (ts)}
- Is growing every day (today it's 41k entries)

My goal:

- To produce a top 10 of most viewed user id's in the table user_view_tracker

My current code is working, but killing the database slowly:

```
select 
distinct uvt.uid as UID,
(select count(*) from user_view_tracker temp where temp.uid=uvt.uid and temp.ts>date_sub(now(),interval 1 month)) as CLICK 
from user_view_tracker uvt 
order by CLICK 
limit 10
```

It's quite obvious that a different data structure would help. But I can't do that as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, delete that subquery, this should be enough ;)

```
select  
    uvt.uid as UID
    ,count(*) as CLICK 
from 
    user_view_tracker uvt 
where 
    uvt.ts > date_sub(now(),interval 1 month)
group by 
    uvt.uid
order by CLICK DESC
limit 10
```

Comment: Edited, you are right. I would like to know why his code is working :D

Comment: Talking about the order by without DESC

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select uid, count(*) as num_stamps
  from user_view_tracker
 where ts > date_sub(now(), interval 1 month)
 group by uid
 order by 2 desc limit 10
```

I kept your criteria as far as getting the count for just the past month. You can remove that line if you want to count all.

The removal of DISTINCT should improve performance. It is not necessary if you aggregate in your outer query and group by uid, as that will aggregate the data to one row per uid with the count.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) in MySQL

```
SELECT UID, COUNT(ts) as Number_Of_Views FROM user_view_tracker
GROUP BY UID  
ORDER BY Number_Of_Views DESC
LIMIT 10
```

A simple demo which selects the top 10 UID viewed
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/907c10/3